# Web Development Tools Question - Automatic File Upload

Tags: ftp

This should a quick question for some easy rep.

I'm doing some PHP Website development, decided to check out and play around with jQuery as well. I don't want to install and manage a local PHP server/service, but I would like a quick one click method for automatically uploading the PHP file I'm working on to my hosting service so I can test it live.

I'm looking into some different editors like Komodo Edit, Notepad++ but I'm wondering what tool has the ability to one click FTP for me?

---

Edit after a few posts came in:

Well Shoot, Ultra Edit costs around $100, and Aptana allows you to upload to their "Cloud", but you have to purchase the cloud space. I already have my own server. I'll have look into BlueFish a bit more....Thanks for the help guys.

I'm thinking I might try using Notepad++ and just write a batch file to run windows built in FTP, make a connection and copy all the files in a folder in auto-overwrite mode. Seem feasible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a setup that I use FileZilla as the FTP, and NotePad++ as my text editor.

Within FileZilla, I set NotePad++ as the default text editor, and when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> within the file I am working on at that time, it automatically uploads those changes to the server.

You will be able to edit the preferences within FileZilla (http://filezilla-project.org) to set your default text editor, this is something you should be able to do with any FTP program.

Check out this post for more information: http://linhost.info/2008/01/notepad-and-filezilla-tip/

Comment: Additionally you can use AutoHotKey to automatically click ok to FileZilla upload request dialog: http://www.trap17.com/index.php/Auto-upload-Files-Filezilla-Autohotkey_t59727.html

Answer (score 1):

[UEStudio](http://www.ultraedit.com) has integrated (S)FTP, SVN, etc, plus the ability to open a file over FTP - of course, it actually just downloads to a temp file, but each time you press save, it uploads it to the server again.

I'm pretty much obliged to point out just now that you might want to reconsider your decision to avoid a local development environment. Using [XAMPP](http://www.xampp.org), it's ridiculously easy to set up a local web server. There are a multitude of benefits to this, far too many to list, even.

Answer (score 1):

The [Aptana IDE](http://www.aptana.com) can do one-click upload via FTP and also synchronize all files between your local environment and remote server (based on timestamps) with one click as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/) can edit the file directly on the FTP server. I'm not sure if the [Win32](http://code.google.com/p/bluefish-win/) version can do that though.

Answer (score 0):

Most advanced editors/IDE's like Zend Studio allow adding FTP servers and editing files directly. Once modified, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> would update the file on server.

Answer (score 0):

i use e-texteditor. It's some kind of textmate clone, only is better :P

Answer (score 0):

I have used sublime text with sftp pluggin. 
[sublime3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) and 
[sftp pluggin](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp)
You only need to config sftp file on root folder.
Works quite good.
Regards